# Looking for jquery library for tagging like Stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, tags

For my website, I need to find a library to put Tags in square boxes like Stackoverflow does. And when you put your mouse on the tag, a screen shows up. On that screen, you can display a long text and links.

Does anyone know such a library ?

thanks

Comment: SO is generally not the place for generic questions like this. If you're looking for plugins and other widgets you may want to ask on the jQuery forums - http://forum.jquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a Tag like feature (the one you insert in Questions) you can use this JQuery Plugin called [tagit](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) here's an example using tag it

The javascript code..

```
var sampleTags = ['c++', 'java', 'php', 'coldfusion', 'javascript', 'asp', 'ruby', 'python', 'c', 'scala', 'groovy', 'haskell', 'perl', 'erlang', 'apl', 'cobol', 'go', 'lua'];


          $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
        });
```

And the html

```
    <p>                 
         <input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="Apple, Orange" disabled="true"> 
    </p>
       <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul>
```

As for the function where you hover and display a long text and links, I think you should implement that on your own,